# 'will attract' vs. 'will be attractive to'

Tags: difference

Which one is better? What are the differences of these two sentences?

> Men will be attractive to women.
>   Men will attract women.

Comment: if you write a report, use the shorter version. if you write a novel, use what expresses better your intention and if you write a poem ...

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to explain this best I can after I change the example sentences:

> Light will be attractive to moths.
>    Light will attract moths.

There's really not much difference in meaning, only in emphasis. Both sentences explain how, if you leave a light bulb on at night in the summertime, you're likely to find moths around it rather quickly.

The first one is more direct; it is stated as a fact. The second one explains why the moths will surround the light bulb, but the reader has to infer the consequences.

In other words, the first sentence focuses on the *reason*, while the second focuses on the *result*.

Your sentences are structured the same way, but, they were more difficult for me to analyze, because, in the real world, the result isn't so inevitable. I think your sentences would be more realistic if they said:

> Some men might be attractive to women.
>    Some men can attract women.